# How to use javascript arguments in the filter method?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am not able to use arguments in the filter method. The confusing part is when I console.log(arguments[1]) I will get 2. Also, when I use 2 as a filter it works. But as soon as I use arguments[1] it does not filter it out. 
Case in point:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values

var newArray = a.filter(function(val){
return val != arguments[1]; ///////////will NOT work//////////////
});
return newArray;

}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

However, the following works:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values

var newArray = a.filter(function(val){
return val != 2; ///////////will work//////////////
});
return newArray;

}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: arguments[1] is taken from the function that you pass in the filter method

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` you're trying to access isn't the one from `destroyer` but from the callback function of `array.filter`. You will have to either name that argument or temporarily store `arguments[1]` into a variable and use that variable instead.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var arg1 = arguments[1];

  return a.filter(function(val){
    return val != arg1;
  });

}

// or

function destroyer(arr, arg1) {

  return a.filter(function(val){
    return val != arg1;
  });

}
```

Comment: Another option would be to use an arrow function. But using a parameter is cleaner anyway IMO.

Comment: @FelixKling There's that. But then considering the OP's code... :D

Answer (score 0):

Inside your filter function, arguments are the arguments passed to that filter function.

So you have to store the destroyer arguments in another variable to use it.

```
// Remove all the values
function destroyer(arr) {

var args = arguments;
var newArray = arr.filter(function(val){

return val != args[1];
});
return newArray;

}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```